# jTree Duplicating Entries when trying to do dynamic updates

Tags: java, jtree

I have been beating my head against a wall all weekend trying to figure this out and have yet to be able to find a bit on here that I can use to resolve the issue.  I am basically trying to do a file view with a jTree, but not have a display view on the side, and only have it running through the jTree.

```
public void getList(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, File f) {
    jTree1.setRootVisible(false);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(null);

    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        if (f.getName().endsWith("msg")) {
            String fTrim = f.getName();

            child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fTrim);
            node.add(child);
        }
    } else {
        //System.out.println("DIRECTORY  -  " + f.getName());
        String fTrim = f.getName();
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fTrim);
        node.add(child);
        File fList[] = f.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(fList[i]);
            getList(child, fList[i]);
        }
    }
    DefaultTreeModel dtm = new DefaultTreeModel(node);
    DefaultTreeModel clear = new DefaultTreeModel(null);
    jTree1.setModel(dtm);
    }
```

Above is what I am using to build the initial list.  I am then using the getList(node, file); command to also try to run an update for the list.  This is working in a sense, however, each time it updates it loads in a duplicate value in the tree as well. Below is how I am calling to try to update the listing,

```
private void jButton1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    getList(root, new File("\\\\hqdata02\\fadata\\ecp call center\\cp - all agents\\Floor Messages\\"));
}
```

The result can be seen below

[At Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oNj6.jpg)

[After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDja1.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated.  At the end of the day, I just want it to update whatever values have changed in the directory.  I also realize that calling getList again, is likely just re-adding all the files in which is causing the issues, I just can't figure out how to get it to update otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't like too bad actually. Your hunch is correct that `getList()` simply re-adds **all** nodes. You have to check whether the current `node` already has a node with the same label. If so, continue with that node instead of creating a new one, or remove it and create a new one. I.e. before `node.add(child);` check `if (!containsChildOfSameName(node, child)`. But... also consider what happens when a file/directory is removed. A more basic solution would be clear all children of the root node and re-create everything again, but that looses all info on expanded state or selection.

Comment: Having an issue... Not seeing anything that references containsChildOfSameName, is this from an independent library?  Currently coding using Java 8.131.

Comment: That one is on you, just used it as a placeholder ;) Shouldn't be too hard to write that as a small helper method, though.